# What segue should I use to do navigation, such as on screenshot below?

Tags: ios, swift

In one russian bank app I found a pretty good navigation I want to implement in my app (Sorry for Russian, hope everything will be clear)

[image]

I'm currently doing Slide-out Navigation panel through that tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Navigator panel is working pretty good.

Now I have such structure. Unfortunately, while clicking on cell, new TableViewController opens on a full screen, and I want it to inherit position from main side view controller.

[image]

In a nutshell, how my side bar work. I'm managing 3 controllers, MainViewController, SidePanelViewController and ContainerViewContloller. For all kind of interaction between two controllers the last one is capable for.

This is the source code:

```
    import UIKit
        import QuartzCore

        enum SlideOutState {
             case BothCollapsed
             case LeftPanelExpanded
        }

    class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var centerViewController: ViewController!

    var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed {
        didSet {
            let shouldShowShadow = currentState != .BothCollapsed
            showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow)
        }
    }

    var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
    centerViewController.delegate = self

    // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
    // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

  }

}

let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

extension ContainerViewController: CenterViewControllerDelegate {

    func toggleLeftPanel() {

        let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

        if notAlreadyExpanded {
            addLeftPanelViewController()
        }

        animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)

    }

    func toggleRightPanel() {
    }

    func addLeftPanelViewController() {

        if (leftViewController == nil) {
            leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
            leftViewController!.categories = Category.allCats()

            addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
        }

    }

    func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
        view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

        addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
        sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }


    func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand shouldExpand: Bool) {

        if (shouldExpand) {
            currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
        } else {
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
                self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

                self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil;
            }
        }

    }

    func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
            }, completion: completion)
    }

    func showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow: Bool) {
        if (shouldShowShadow) {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        } else {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        }
    }

}


private extension UIStoryboard {
  class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

  class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }


  class func centerViewController() -> ViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? ViewController
  }

}
```

So, I'm not sure, that for that tableviewcontroller I should write the same rules, as for side controller, what can you suggest?

Comment: Looks like the side panel in this case is actually an instance of `UINavigationController` and it's just pushing onto it when the top cell is tapped like regular

Comment: The left most view controller in your image should be embedded in the navigation controller, not the right most.  i.e. it should be NavController->VC1->City

Comment: SWRevealViewController, https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController, is very clear and easy to use if you would prefer trying it